# Carrier Fan Coil Unit heat function does not come on

Tags: thermostat

FCU  model # 42SGA03   Fan works, cooling function works, but heat does not

1H/1C T stat Honeywell Focus pro 4000
Hot water  and chilled water supply and return pipes

terminals W ( heat ) Y( Cool) G( fan )  R/Rc( line voltage )  C( common)
I measure 24 volts at all terminals in backing plate with T stat removed,  ( R-W; R-Y: R-C; ) except fan ( R W )
Continuity between R and all other terminals
Also some continuity between W and Y terminal, and between the  wires themselves for the W and Y
I have tried with 2 Thermostats up there,  both new, and neither can get the heat to come on. 
Could I test function by jumping between R and W? or R G and W?

Comment: What's the wiring like in the unit?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer my own question. I checked the thermostat again, and this time I flipped the switch that says 1) for gas or oil  and 2) for electric ( thermostat controls fan). Running with the switch at 2), the fan operates and  I think the heat comes on. I will try it again tomorrow with my multimeter, checking for temperature rise.